# CodeLite for C++ with OpenCV in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: c++, ide, opencv

I can compile a sample C++ Code (including OpenCV) using both CMake and following command line:

```
g++ cv.cpp -o cvapp `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`
```

But I want to use *CodeLite IDE* for this purpose. I have added `/usr/include/opencv;/usr/include/opencv2` in the **Include Paths** under **compiler** tab in project settings. And added `/usr/local/lib` in **Libraries Search Path** under **Linker** tab.

But still, I am getting errors shown in this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPmco.jpg) for a sample code. 
Now is it possible to use CodeLite for OpenCV coding environment? If yes then how?

Comment: Specifying an additional library search path via `-L` is not sufficient - you will need to link the specific libraries (`-lopencv` and so on)

Comment: I have got a working answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45176692/using-codelite-ide-for-opencv-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts/45177793#45177793)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just need to add

> `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`

in **Linker Options** under linker tab in project settings.

[image]